# Minimizing the number of operations of subtracting one so as to get to $0$

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, puzzle

[image]

Hello Community! The above problem you see is a combinatorics problem, more like an algorithmic problem that I could not solve. :(

This problem requires that every child gets satisfied. In brief terms, this problem asks you to choose one number and subtract $1$ from the rest of the numbers and eventually we have to get to $0$ in all of them. We have to do this as least times as possible.

I tried hit and trial one by one but how can I guarantee to find the minimum value?

> Also, if you have seen the other posts I have made in a while, it can be observed that all these problems that I am posting right now are pretty unusual combinatorics problems and I seriously need some help on how to solve these. Can anybody please suggest me some problem solving strategies for these kind of problems?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Are these questions from some exam paper or competition somewhere?

Comment: Yes These are from a paper called Zonal Informatics Olympiad Past Papers held in India. I am asking these problems because they are AIME level problems (and HMMT). BTW thanks for the link!

Comment: When you ask these questions, you really should mention where you got them from, because otherwise people might not want to help you because they could think you are trying to cheat your way through active contest. Also, please actually enter the text of the question rather than just an image so that people using the search facilities of MSE will be able to find it.