# Finding the number of arrangements where the order is constrained and then dividing into groups

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, puzzle

[image]

Hello everybody! The above problem you see is a problem I could not solve. :(

Basically this problem, I guess, is asking us to arrange the courses into the order wanted and dividing the courses into the minimum number of semesters. But I am having a lot of difficulty apparently on how to arrange them and find the minimum number of semesters we want. I tried going one by one, step by step to solve this problem but that doesn't work especially for the longer parts. :( I think we'll have to think of an algorithmic approach to this problem but how? I know the answers and they are: $7,6,5,8$..

BTW I have asked some more problems. Can anybody please help me with them?

[Finding the number of ways in which columns can be connected such that even number of specific columns are selected.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3422677/finding-the-number-of-ways-in-which-columns-can-be-connected-such-that-even-numb)

[Arranging objects where some $depend$ upon some other(s)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3422578/arranging-objects-where-some-depend-upon-some-others)

[Finding the subsets of people sitting around a circular tables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3422523/finding-the-subsets-of-people-sitting-around-a-circular-tables)

[Minimizing the number of operations of subtracting one so as to get to $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3422533/minimizing-the-number-of-operations-of-subtracting-one-so-as-to-get-to-0)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You might be interested in reading about the Critical Path Method, also known as CPM. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_path_method

Answer (score 1):

You can solve these via [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Comment: Hello Rob! Thank you for your idea but this problem is from a pen and paper exam and additionally I have no idea of Computer Science. Therefore, I would anticipate any other mathematical solution. Thanks.

Comment: For these small instances, you can implement the topological sort by pen and paper. Start by drawing a directed graph with one node per course and a directed arc for each precedence constraint.